# Azure Devops BUild scripts Are Restore Build and Test Required

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

In Azure Devops for a .Net core application.

I have three steps

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
dotnet test
```

But if I simply run dotnet test that forces a restore and build. Is there any reason to have the first two steps?

Comment: Seperate logging for problem analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them as follows:

```sh
dotnet restore
dotnet build --no-restore
dotnet test --no-build
```

In this way, you will speed up your build as it can use result of the previous command.

This is default behavior so you don't need to always run all commands to run dotent test for instance. It is convinient and still possible to opt-out from thah behavior.